# Installation not successful. Dash Home unavailable

Tags: system-installation

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Dimension 5150 attached to a Dell 2009wt monitor. It is running alongside Windows XP Pro, which is working fine.

The Ubuntu installation is not working. I cannot access the Dash Home button after I log in. When I try to do so, I get a flickering horizontal band across the top of the screen. Apps in the launcher (Firefox, Libreoffice) run ok, but occasionally they freeze.

I reinstalled it from the installation disk and the problem persisted.

I ran the following commands in a terminal (accessed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> because Dash Home not functioning)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It still didn't work.

I also ran

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

The problem still persists.

Any suggestion as to how I might proceed would be greatly appreciated. My instinct suggests it might be to do with the monitor/graphics card.

In the terminal I got the following from "lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'"

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370 [Radeon X300]
Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 0602
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset unity by

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ && unity --reset-icons &disown
```

After this change display to graphical with Ctrl+Alt+F7 or (F8).
If this doesn't work instantly, restart the system.

Comment: Thank you Ratnakar

I tried the above and it did not work. I am on the problem PC replying to you, so as you can see it is partly working. The Dash Home is still unavailable and as before. My suspicion re. the graphics card/monitor is based on the flashing that happens when I mouse over the launcher. Maybe it's not the problem.

Comment: maybe you can try from compiz manager.  

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

and when it is installed ,  on terminal 

DISPLAY=:0 ccsm